# Can I develop for Android without an Android phone?

Tags: android

I don't have an Android phone, is there still a way I can learn Android? How can I learn and what do I need?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, absolutely ... the android SDK comes with an emulator, which, while quirky in some ways, does a pretty good job of letting you at least start learning and running most sample projects.

*edit: This thread is somewhat old, but in recent times a new emulator has been released that is quite nice. Check out [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) :)*

Comment: In fact, many programmers wind up using the emulator anyway, because the Android platform is used for so many different phones that you can't possibly test your code on each physical model.

Comment: but the problem is that emulator is quite slow...
It frequently hangs on my window 7 64 bit, i-5 laptop which has 4 gb RAM

Comment: @Formosus, see the edit I just made ... there's another option available :)

Answer (score 4):

To add to Joel Martinezs answer,

Yes you can learn android dev without having a device, although it is really good to have one if you are into dev.

I started 3 months back and this is what i did

1. Downloaded the sdk and tools
2. Created a hello world app
3. Read about android sdk best practices in the developers site.
4. Looked at a lot of sample apps to know how they work
5. Started creating our app.

If I could do it, I am sure you could do it too. Android development is very easy to get started. You have all the info you need in the android developers site. If you need any help we are here at StackOVerFlow :-)

Answer (score 2):

As Joel puts it, you can use the emulator. Here is the [developer website](http://developer.android.com/index.html), and here is the page specific to the [emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html).

Answer (score 2):

You need to fulfill  the following requirements

- Java knowledge
- Android sdk
- Android simulator
- working knowledge of android OS(you can get it using emulator)
- creativity and logics
- Finally, a video tutorial(I suggest [lynda.com](http://www.lynda.com/Android-2-tutorials/Android-App-Development-with-Java-Essential-Training/79825-2.html?srchtrk=index:2%0Alinktypeid:2%0Aq%3aandroid%0Apage:1%0As%3arelevance%0Asa%3atrue%0Aproducttypeid:2))
- Also take a look into [android developer official site](http://developer.android.com/index.html)

Comment: Java knowledge ? i am a php developer and i have knowledge of web based  JavaScript

Comment: Oh. Please refer to the [link](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex.html). Flex is very flexible in technology and the product OS. With same code you can create app for android, blackberry and iOS.

Answer (score 2):

Hey in addition to the above answers,

u should actually test on ur device when u r making an app that uses one of the following :

1. GPS, or wi-fi to get user location
2. when u want to use any phone sensor in ur app
3. when u r trying to integrate camera/ camcorder in your app
4. also u might need to actually test phone call/sms functionality integrated in an app

otherwise the emulator just works fine

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Just get an android emulator and use that for your development.  there are free emulators available online as well as tutorials and lots of books available for android OS development.